# Plants under different sunlight

Tags: science-based, xenobiology, flora, stars

What would a plant look like under a different sunlight. Like for example, O, B, A, F, K, and M-types? I know what a plant would look like under a G-type star like our Sun, what about under a star different from ours?

Comment: I asked something similar and got some great answers -- you might want to [check this out.]( http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/63259/what-colour-is-the-foliage-if-the-sky-is-violet)

Comment: He means [this](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/63259/what-colour-is-the-foliage-if-the-sky-is-violet)

Comment: @WillowRex Note that you can delete your comment and repost it in a correct form.

Comment: @Glorfindel  yes, but then PythonMaster's help looks ridiculous. I figure my learning helps others -- so if you are a mod -- feel free to fix it. I am happy with my error showing.

Comment: As much as I would like a page to go to when designing Planet X around Star of Type Y, answers will have to **provide info for a lot of scenarios**, each of which may have **many correct answers**. I would consider making each spectral type its own question, otherwise this is *very* broad.

Comment: Are we to assume you intend an Earth-like world for each of these stars? Otherwise, answers will have to provide details about the planet, such as atmosphere and soil composition, as these have an impact on life.

Comment: @Glorfindel then you flag the looking-rediculus one as “obsolete”.

Answer (score 1):

I can answer that!  Well...kinda, I can give some ideas.

As you might remember from school, plants are green because of chlorophyll, a substance plants use to absorb sunlight to make food.  It's green because the most intense color light emitted by Sol is green; if they take in too much at once, then it basically hurts the plant.  So green plants are the most efficient at absorbing light from a G-class star.
Other such chemical compounds have colors like orange, red, yellow, even purple.  These are less efficient than chlorophyll, but they're good for fallback options.  These might be better, tho, around other types of stars.  Which ones would work best where, I dunno, but it's safe to mention that dimmer stars will, in general, tend to have darker plants.  Imagine forests of black trees facing a red dwarf star, absorbing all the light it can...

For more info, I'd recommend taking a look at these two videos by MinuteEarth.
https://youtu.be/aAQYpra4aUs (Part 1)
https://youtu.be/545rqaOJQD8 (Part 2)

Comment: No prob!  Happy to help!